# $\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{4}} \sec ^5(x) \, dx$

Tags: calculus

I am wondering how to use integration by part and the reduction formula to solve this integral

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{4}} \sec ^5(x) \, dx$$

The answer in the book is:

$\frac{\sqrt{2} *7}{8}+\frac{3}{5} \ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Comment: [Secant Integral Reduction Formula](http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=10932)

Comment: hint: $\sec^5 x = \sec^3 x \cdot \sec^2 x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified tremendously using a secant integral reduction formula posted by GohP.iHan in the comments above. But if you are a calculus student you have probably not encountered proof by induction and should practice doing this integral the "hard" way. First  you should be able to see that$$\sec^5(x) = \sec^3(x)\sec^2(x) \\ = \sec^3(x)(\tan^2(x)+1) \\ = \sec(x)(\tan^2(x)+1)(\tan^2(x)+1) \\ = \sec(x)\tan^4(x)+2\sec(x)\tan^2(x)+\sec(x)$$ So you want to find $$\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^4(x)+2\sec(x)\tan^2(x)+\sec(x) dx \\ =\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^4(x)dx+2\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^2(x)dx+\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(x)dx $$ I'll help you calculate the middle integral and then you can take it from there. Using integration by parts on the middle integral, let $$u = \tan(x) \quad du= \sec^2(x)dx \\ dv = \sec(x)\tan(x)dx \quad v = \sec(x)$$ Then $$2\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^2(x)dx = 2\tan(x)\sec(x)-2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec^3(x)dx \\ = 2\tan(x)\sec(x)-2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(x)\tan^2(x)+\sec(x)dx \\ = 2\tan(x)\sec(x)-2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(x)\tan^2(x)-2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(x)dx$$ Now add the quantity $2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(x)\tan^2(x)$ to both sides of this integral equation to get $$4\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^2(x)dx = 2\tan(x)\sec(x)-2\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(x)dx \\ \implies 2\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^2(x)dx = \tan(x)\sec(x)-\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(x)dx$$ Now that you have an expression for $2\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^2(x)dx$, you can replace it in your original equation that you need to solve, so you'll get $$\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^4(x)dx+2\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^2(x)dx+\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(x)dx \\ = \int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^4(x)dx+\left(\tan(x)\sec(x)-\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(x)dx\right)+\int_0^{\pi/4}\sec(x)dx \\ =\tan(x)\sec(x)+ \int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^4(x)dx $$ You should get more nice cancellations when you evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec(x)\tan^4(x)dx $.